# How do I installing Python 3.9.6 on Windows 10 Pro (when there is another version installed) - installer fails?

Tags: python, python3

This is extremely frustrating, ideally I would like to get in touch with the Python installer team to fix the installer.

I am attempting to install Python 3.9.6 on my system.

I previously installed Python 3.8.1, 3.9.7 and 3.10.0 with no issues.

I have a project that specifically requires 3.9.6 (is the latest AWS Lambda runtime).  Whe I run the installer (python-3.9.6-amd64.exe), it gives an error dialog

```
Setup failed
0x80070666 - Another version of this product is already installed.
Installation of this version cannot continue.  
To configure or remove the existing version of this product, 
use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
```

**When I goto Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel**, I do not see Python 3.9.6 there (only 3.8.1, 3.9.7, 3.10.0),

Why can those three versions be installed when there is another version, but 3.9.6 cannot?
Can this be fixed please (if the python installer teams is seeing this).

I am selecting do not add to system env vars, do not install for all users, do not create a shortcut, I just need it on my system.

I tried the embedded .zip, but that does not come with site-packages or pip.

Comment: Python 3.8 3.9 and 3.10 are major releases which can be installed in parallel. But 3.9.6 is just a minor update of 3.9 and additionally it is an older update of that branch. I would assume that this is the reason why you can't install it.

Comment: This has never happened to me and  find it strange. Provided you remove all the Python installations from the environment variables (and use different directories - this should go without saying). Try using `where Python` from CMD as you successively remove installations from the PATH, because you're installing for one user account you may find there's an installation in `User\AppData\Local\...` my advice would be to remove those and install to folders that are easily accessible.

Comment: Make sure you don't have [one of these somewhere on your system](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-microsoft-store-package). If this method of successively removing the installations fails, try once to install for all users (there used to be a rarely mentioned windows bug that made user specific installations unusable - I can't find a reference for it). If all else fails, try an alternative like anaconda do isolate the installation from the OS. If you want to try [something no one else uses](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows)...

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether you have 32-bit or 64-bit versions installed, but my personal observation has been that branches of the same "bitness" apparently cannot be installed together.

So e.g. installing `python-3.9.7.exe` (32-bit) and `python-3.9.6-amd64.exe` (64-bit) should be fine, but installing `python-3.9.7-amd64.exe` (64-bit) and `python-3.9.6-amd64.exe` (64-bit) would produce the error you're encountering.

Without uninstalling any version of Python, the quickest solution here might be to try `python-3.9.6.exe` (32-bit) instead. But obviously you could try replacing Python 3.9.7 with the 32-bit version if you really need Python 3.9.6 in 64-bit as well.